# Modifying CSS properties associated to a given CSS class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JavaScript color picker linked to a text input. I would like several colored elements on my to change their color on the update of that color input. I could create several classes, one for each color (blue, red, green, etc), but i would like to have the whole 24 bits coloe palette, not just a few of them.
Is it possible to modify the value of the properties associated to a given CSS class ? If yes, will modifying these values apply new values on the rendered page in real time ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is jQuery an option, because this would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Yes i'm using jQuery, flemingstone's answer fixed my problem.

Comment: Ok. Next time, designate that in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally possible, and yes it will be updated in real time.

Here is a function to do the class property update, tied to a mouseover event (requires jQuery 1.0+). Mousing over div with id myDiv will update the CSS background color to white for all div's with class myColorDivs:

```
$('#myDiv').mouseover(function() {

    $('.myColorDivs').css('background', '#fff');

});
```

Comment: Note that there's a difference between modifying the CSS rule for a class, and directly modifying elements with the class. If a new element with the class were added, for example, it would not be affected by the change.

Comment: That's exactly right. I'm just modifying elements already present on the page in my example, not modifying the actual class itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It's not exactly was i wanted to do but it will do the trick. If i need to add an element i can still precrate it or reperform that style update, even it's not really clean on the perfomance side.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm late ...
Had the same question some days before and didn't find a practical answer.
Here's how I solved it for me (requires jquery):

Add an inline-stylesheet after all other stylesheets your page may need with the class you want to change.
Assign a TITLE Attribute to this stylesheet!

```
<style title="tomrulez" type="text/css">
/*the stylesheet to change - Note the TITLE*/
.shaded{
    color:green;
}
</style>
```

Add this function:

```
    function modCSS (stylesheet, rule, attrib, newval){
    $.each( document.styleSheets, function( skey, svalue ) {
        if(svalue.title==stylesheet){
            $.each(svalue.cssRules,function (rkey,rvalue){
                if (rvalue.selectorText==rule){
                    rvalue.style[attrib]=newval;
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
```

call it like this:

```
<div onclick="modCSS('tomrulez','.shaded','color','red')"> click here</div>
```

Parameters are:

- **stylesheet** -> the TITLE of the last stylesheet on your page
- **rule** -> The CSS-rule you want to change
- **attrib** -> The attribute of the rule you want the change
- **newval** -> The new value you want to assign to that attribute

I've tested this with Firefox, Chrome and IE10.
IE may not work in older Versions. But I develop mainly backends for a small group of users that do not use IE if i tell them (Yep, i'm a lucky about that!)

Btw. Here is a Plunker that works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/EMDpjU06U2p83Df8Lolq?p=preview