# Is there any way to change CSS Class that registered in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I explain the problem by a simple example.
I have the following html page. It's simple.

There is one CSS Class named TestDiv and two javascript function.

1. **addDiv** creates new div and appends it to page by clicking on button *"add new div"*.
2. **setBlue** is the function that i want to change the color of divs that has class **TestDiv** and *I dont know how*.

You can see that i wrote some code to change the current generated Divs inside the **setBlue** function. But I don't know how i can change the class to affect the new divs that will generated by **addDiv** function after that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .TestDiv {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function addDiv() {
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div")
            newDiv.className = "TestDiv";
            newDiv.innerHTML = "test";
            document.getElementById("firstDiv").insertBefore(newDiv);
        }
        function setBlue() {

            var currentDivList=document.getElementsByClassName("TestDiv");
            for(var i=0;i<currentDivList.length;i++){
                currentDivList[i].style.color = "blue";
            }
            // What i can write here to change the TestDiv css class
            // And after that, new (div)s will generate by new color(changed css class)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstDiv" class="TestDiv">
        test
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="add new div" onclick="addDiv();"/>
    <input type="button" value="change color to blue" onclick="setBlue();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8M3xs/

Comment: What is your desired result. You are not explaining your question correctly

Comment: I don't think you will be able to change styles of a page. You will probably need to store the fact that you have a new colour and check for this in the `addDiv()` function to set it to the newly added divs.

Comment: @ComFreek if you add a div and press the `change color` button it will only change the current items, he wants the change to also effect newly created items after they have changed the color.

Comment: I still dont get what the OP really wants...

Comment: Have a look at this answer I gave some time ago. This will in fact change the CSS Rule. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719429/modifying-css-properties-associated-to-a-given-css-class-using-javascript/19030515#19030515

Comment: @MohammadNouraein Can't you just attach a different class to `newDiv` after it's created the first time? I.e. store the class name into a (global?) variable, and then change the value of that variable at the place where you want to do the change. If you want to change the appearance of the `TestDiv`, just change the name of the class: `TestDiv.className = some_other_class_name;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend adding or modifying CSS rules on-the-fly, but there are several solutions:

- Modify the original CSS rule

  ```
  <style id="myStyle">
      .TestDiv {
          color:red;
      }
  </style>

  ...

  var myStyle = document.getElementById("myStyle");
  myStyle.sheet.cssRules.item(0).cssText = ".TestDiv { color: blue }";
  ```

  (I had to assign an ID to the style tag because I couldn't get it work in the jsFiddle environment otherwise. It should equally be possible by using `document.styleSheets[0]`.)
- Add a CSS rule to a newly created style sheet (thanks to [pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879/pawel)!)

  ```
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  style.sheet.addRule(".TestDiv", "color: blue");
  ```
- Add raw CSS text to a newly created style sheet:
  [→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M3xs/1/)

  ```
  var sheet = document.createElement('style')
  sheet.innerHTML = ".TestDiv { color: blue }";
  document.body.appendChild(sheet);
  ```

Comment: This seems fine to me

Comment: Would adding a new style tag overwrite the previous one? Wouldn't it get confused with having multiple class declarations on the same page?

Comment: @Nunners Yes, it does 'overwrite' the old one. The old still exists, but the browser only uses the new one for styling. That's standard behavior.

Comment: I think this is more elegant: http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets but the solution proposed here is good as well.

Comment: @Nunners - nope. The rules 'overwrite' previously declared rules. I.e the newest rule's attributes overwrite previous ones. E.g `.someClass{color: red; font-weight: bold;}` later followed by `.someClass{color: green;}` will cause elements of `someClass` to be displayed as bold text, in green - however, both exist. If the second rules is removed later, the text will again be shown as bold and in red.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for the clarification, never needed to know about this and it's a good thing to know. :)

Comment: @pawel I cannot get it to work, possibly due to the jsFiddle environment (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8M3xs/3)).

Comment: @ComFreek I've edited your fiddle to use `.addRule` http://jsfiddle.net/8M3xs/4/ or without creating a new `style` element: http://jsfiddle.net/8M3xs/6/

Comment: @pawel Thanks for your input! I updated my answer (I even got it to work to modify the original CSS rule).

Answer (score 2):

`style.color` creates an inline style that overrides the class styles. In order to retain whether `setBlue()` has been clicked store a var either `isBlue = false` or `divClass = 'blue'/'red'` and toggle a class on all the divs which retains your color styles:

http://jsbin.com/IdadUz/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a stylesheet to the `head` section:

```
function setBlue() {
    var currentDivList=document.getElementsByClassName("TestDiv");
    for (var i=0; i < currentDivList.length; i++) {
        currentDivList[i].style.color = "blue";
    }

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = ".TestDiv { color: blue; }";
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please people, try to comment the answers when you downvote them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly modify style elements that have been created on the page or in external Style Sheets, one way to do this would be with the following javascript :

```
var newColor = '';

function addDiv() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div")
    newDiv.className = "TestDiv";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "test";
    document.getElementById("firstDiv").insertBefore(newDiv);

    if (newColor != '') {
        newDiv.style.color = newColor;
    }
}

function setBlue() {

    var currentDivList = document.getElementsByClassName("TestDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < currentDivList.length; i++) {
        currentDivList[i].style.color = "blue";
    }

    newColor = 'blue';
}
```

When you click on the Change Color button it will set the `newColor` variable to `blue`. Then when you add a new div it will check if this variable has been set, if so it will change the style.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr3Ct/)

Comment: This is good idea. but for simple purpose. I work on a big CSS file and there is more than one property (color). you have creative mind. tank you.

Comment: Thank you, for future reference it might be better to mention your example is a stream-lined version of a much larger item, you'll most likely get more helpful answers about your issue. :)